# Using CASE within a single query to update multiple columns in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I wanted to write an update query to update multiple columns in a SQL table as `BLANKS` wherever their current value is `NULL`.

I wrote a query like the one below but it does not seem to have updated correctly all the appropriate rows where some / all of these column(s) are having `NULL`.

```
Update A SET     
A.Col1 = CASE WHEN A.COl1 is NULL THEN ' ' END,     
A.Col2 = CASE WHEN A.COl2 is NULL THEN ' ' END,    
A.Col3 = CASE WHEN A.COl3 is NULL THEN ' ' END,    
A.Col4 = CASE WHEN A.COl4 is NULL THEN ' ' END    
FROM Table1 A
```

Is there anything wrong with the query above? Can we not use `CASE` in the way how I have used above?

Comment: You probably overwrote all NON-NULL values with NULL when you ran it the first time!!!

Comment: Thanks Salman... So adding the ELSE part to each of the CASE statement would solve the problem is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use either `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`

Example

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET
ColumnName1 = ISNULL(ColumnName1,' '),
ColumnName2 = COALESCE(ColumnName2,' ')
WHERE <Condition>
```

or if you still wish to use `CASE` specify the Column name in the `ELSE` because otherwise, the Data will be set to `NULL` for all Not Null fields

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET
ColumnName1 = CASE WHEN ColumnName1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ColumnName1 END
WHERE <Condition>
```

Comment: `COALESCE(x, y)` is just a shorter form of a `CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN x ELSE y END`

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
UPDATE A SET 

A.Col1 = ISNULL(A.COl1, ' '),

A.Col2 = ISNULL(A.COl2, ' '),

A.Col3 = ISNULL(A.COl3, ' '),

A.Col4 = ISNULL(A.COl4, ' ')

FROM Table1 A
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `ELSE` in `CASE` expression  :

```
Update A 
     SET A.Col1 = CASE WHEN A.COl1 is NULL THEN ' ' ELSE A.Col1 END,
         . . . 
FROM Table1 A;
```

Also you can filter the `NULL` values with `WHERE` clause instead to avoid `CASE` expression  :

```
Update A 
     SET A.Col1 = ' ',
     . . . 
FROM Table1 A
WHERE A.Col1 IS NULL AND . . . ;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for your comments... But there is no dependency between col1, col2, col3 & col4 for the NULL condition and I do not want write 4 different queries to update the Table1.. Hence went for the CASE logic...